Sharepoint List - Custom Format column - Unable to vertically align or fill with flex
I have a SharePoint list with custom column formatting, which works perfectly until the text in another column has too many lines, then vertical centering is not working and the coloring does not cover the entire space.
The aim is to have the color in the title column fill the space entirely, as you can see in the green box it works with one or two lines.
But then I have items where there is 5 lines of text and the box doesn't cover the entire thing (red)
Problem visualisation
Here's the current code that I have. I tried changing flex direction to column, setting height to 100% and some other flex properties, but it's been many years since I've worked with CSS and simply don't remember what the solution here should be.
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
    "display": "flex",
    
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "100%",
    "align-items": "center"
    
    },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgViolet 
              sp-field-borderLeftRegular 
              sp-field-borderLeftSolid 
              sp-css-borderColor-LightGrayFont 
              sp-field-fontSizeMedium 
              sp-css-color-LightGrayFont sp-field-bold"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Title]"


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
